# PCC-S-02016, include file pathname is too long

Tags: c++, sun

I am trying to compile a C++ application on SUN server using the compiler Sun C++ 5.9 SunOS_sparc Patch 124863-01.
While compiling I am getting the below error:

```
PCC-S-02016, include file pathname is too long
Error at line 22, column 10 in file /export/home/bscs/billing1/bscsprod/billing/
compilation/opt_nc/hpux11.x/xalan/include/xalanc/PlatformSupport/XalanXMLChar.hp
p
#include <xalanc/PlatformSupport/PlatformSupportDefinitions.hpp>
.........1
PCC-S-02015, unable to open include file
Error at line 37, column 10 in file BillImageRef.pcpp
EXEC SQL BEGIN DECLARE SECTION;
.........1
PCC-S-02016, include file pathname is too long
```

Do you have any Idea how to solve this issue?
Thank you in advance
Regards

Answer (score 1):

PCC-02016: include file pathname is too long
Cause: The pathname for include files exceeded the maximum length of 80 characters.

Action: Move the include file, or create an environment variable or logical to shorten the pathname.

Read your beloved documentation [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28278/pcc2us.htm)

Comment: you mean that this path on the hpp file "#include <xalanc/PlatformSupport/PlatformSupportDefinitions.hpp>" is too long??
should I modify the include clause here?

Comment: Did you check what is on line 22? That's where the compiler said the error was at: [Error at line 22, column 10 in file /export/home/bscs/billing1/bscsprod/billing/
compilation/opt_nc/hpux11.x/xalan/include/xalanc/PlatformSupport/XalanXMLChar.hp
p]

Comment: just the include is there   22  #include <xalanc/PlatformSupport/PlatformSupportDefinitions.hpp>

Answer (score 0):

Use a batch file. And withing the file include the required directory as additional include directory reference.